# App Not installing on ipad device

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

I am testing the app on clients device with adhoc distribution but it not installing on the device can you tell me the steps how to identify the error why it is not installing i have installed all the necessary provisioning on clients device but still app is not runing.

Comment: Are You sure add client device Udid add in distribution provision File

Comment: yes it is added in the distribuition profile

Comment: please check Device Ios and Project Ios Development Target

Comment: my device iOS is 4.2 and deployment target is also 4.2 but Development iOS is 5.0

Comment: please check code singing ientify when build item

Comment: what to check in code signing identity this app works on other device with same profile but not working on this device

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try remove all provision files from Device and Mac. It seems, XCode building with expired Ad Hoc provision. Then install your latest provision and try again your own steps.

**Edited:**

Check in developer.apple.com is device is registered for Ad Hoc provision. It seems is not. And download a latest provision from this site. And try recompile with new provision.

**Edited 2:**

For register device to developer.apple.com :

1) Log in in this site developer.apple.com

2) Click on "iOS Provisioning Portal" link

3) Click "Devices" at left panel

4) Click "Add devices" button at right

5) Enter device name in "Device Name" and device UDID in "Device ID"

6) Click "Submit"

Then update your provision:

1) Click "Provisioning" at left panel

1.5) Click "Distribution"

2) Click "Edit"->"Modify" on your project

3) Set checkbox on your device and click "Submit"

4) Download a new provision file and update.

Comment: i dont get this point becuase i have added two device it works fine on one and it does not install on the second device it seems another problem

Comment: how to check that device is registered for Ad-Hoc or not

Comment: redownload a provision file with new device

Answer (score 0):

Check this out, it will help you a lot [iPhone Distibution Steps](http://www.idev101.com/code/Distribution/)